# Why is Angular $resource polluting my data?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have an API returning the following response

```
{
   "keyA": [1,2,5],
   "keyB": [3,6,4],
   "keyC": [3,2,1]
}
```

And I'm using a very simple service to access the API endpoint

```
var $module = angular.module('mySimpleService', ['ngResource']);

$module.service('MyApiService', function(
    $resource
){
    return {
        entities: $resource('http://myapi.com/data', null, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false,
                responseType: 'json'
            }
        })
    };
});
```

And I'm calling the service like this

```
var apiData = MyApiService.entities.get()
.$promise.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);  
    console.log(Object.keys(data)); 
});
```

When I log out the data and the object keys, I can see that angular has added `$promise` and `$resolved` as properties to my data. Since I need to enumerate the keys, this is a bit inconvenient.

Am I missing a crucial step here? How can I access my raw untainted response?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the promise itself you can use the callback to `.get` to get the entity instance.

```
EntitiesApiService.entities.get(function (entity) {
    // entity is unpolluted
});
```

You could still use `.$promise` to check for failures with `null, function (error) {` and the like.

Comment: Having just tried this, It's still adding `$promise` and `$resolved` to the the response.